# unordered_map over-writing existing element

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to update one class member of an object (which is to be stored in an unordered_map of unordered_maps) and then later update a different class member of the same object.

```
typedef unordered_map<int, X> inner_map;
typedef unordered_map<int, inner_map> outer_map;

struct X{
    Mem a;
    Mem b;
};

void myFunc(outer_map* o_map,
            const Mem* m_obj,
            const int outerkey,
            const int innerkey){

    X local_x;                 // Create local X for inserting when doesn't exist in map

    (*(o_map))[outerkey][innerkey] = local_x;    //Insert if not already present

    if(SOME_VAL == m_obj->Type()){
        (*(o_map))[outerkey][innerkey].a = m_obj;   //Update the 'X::a' member
    }
    else{
        (*(o_map))[outerkey][innerkey].b = m_obj;   //Update the 'X::b' member
    }
}
```

The first time I insert a new `X` object representing `local_x` (because it doesn't currently exist in the maps), then update one of `local_x`'s class members. Later on I wish to update the other class member of the same object. It seems when this happens, I am actually over-writing the already-inserted X object. I thought:

```
(*(o_map))[outerkey][innerkey] = local_x;
```

would only over-write/insert if the key doesn't already exist?

Comment: "I am actually over-writing the already-inserted X object". You mean by a new object of `X`?

Comment: @HappyCoder Yes that is what seems to be happening. After this method is called the second time, only the second class member is non-null.

Comment: Why not read the documentation for `unordered_map` and find out what the various member functions *actually* do rather than programming based on assumptions, guesswork and faith?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/           "If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key"

Comment: And it then returns a reference to that object, or if an object was already there, it returns a reference to that. Which you then overwrite when you say `= local_x;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can be simplified to this:

```
void myFunc(outer_map* o_map, const Mem* m_obj, int outerkey, int innerkey)
{
    X& x = (*o_map)[outerkey][innerkey];
    (SOME_VAL == m_obj->Type() ? x.a : x.b) = *m_obj;
}
```

The `[]`-operator *already* creates a new element if one doesn't already exist at the given key. (What else could it possibly do?)

Comment: Thanks, its nice code. I have a question related to the assignment. X::a and X::b are actually non-const Mem* pointers. The above code produces a compiler error because I am assigning const Mem* m_obj to non-const X::a or X::b. What would be the best solution to handle this?

Comment: Am I wrong declaring this function interface to accept const Mem* ?

Comment: @user997112: It's not exactly *wrong*, it's just weird. Why not use a const reference?